# Serilog ExpressionTemplate rename log level and apply formatting

Tags: serilog

I'm trying to use serilog's `ExpressionTemplate` and write the log level in the following way:

```
{ "level": "INF", ... }
```

I know how to alias `@l` to level - `level: @l`
and I know how to format the level to three upper-case letters - `@l:u3` but I'm unable to combine the two

I have tried the following without success (fails when trying to format the template with an exception):

```
level: @l:u3
```

```
{'level': @l:u3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this is [a limitation in Serilog.Expressions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions/issues/69), which will hopefully be addressed soon.

> **Update:** version 3.4.0-dev-* now on NuGet supports `ToString(@l, 'u3')`.

You can work around it with conditionals:

```
{'level': if @l = 'Information' then 'INF' else if @l = 'Warning' then 'WRN' else 'ERR'}
```

With a few more branches for remaining levels.

(Alternatively, you could write and plug in a [user defined function](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions#implementing-user-defined-functions) along the lines of `ToShortLevel(@l)`, and use that instead.)